# Controlled Input from Redux, onChange Handler

Tags: reactjs, redux, controlled-component

I have controlled input where i set value from redux, how do I set `onChange` handler here

```
<input type="text" className="form-control"
       name="name" placeholder="full name"
       value={user.name} onChange={??} />
```

Comment: Where is user data coming from and how are you planning on storing the input state

Comment: user data is coming from redux. I have destructured the props {user}

Answer (score 1):

As `user` data is a part of redux's store, you update it's value by dispatching an action.

With hooks you use [`useDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch):

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export const CounterComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onChange = (e) => dispatch({ type: `USER_NAME`, name: e.target.value });

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      className="form-control"
      name="name"
      placeholder="full name"
      value={user.name}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
};
```